# Microsoft SQL and query-ing with spelling errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, spell-checking

If I wanted to run a query where certain fields in my query were to be mispelt (up to a certain point of course), is there a native way to do this with MS SQL server or does one have to implement something else entirely?
What I think it boils to is can you select where levenstein distance is a max of X

Example

select from myTable WHERE name closeTo('Erik')

and it might return things like Eric, ie, a Levenhstein distance of 1

Comment: "where certain fields in my query were to be mispelt".. could you clarify this a bit.  It's kind of hard to figure out exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at T-SQL SOUNDEX and DIFFERENCE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx

Comment: That is possibly the most amusing SQL command I have ever seen.